# Android Studio shows symbols in red but it compiles OK

Tags: android, android-studio

The wise ones suggest dramatic solutions. Is there any harm happening? can I hope that it will recover all by itself. Is this a "cloud no bigger than a man's hand" coming to engulf my project in a terrible storm?

Comment: Could you give me example for symbol that are red? are those icons ?

Comment: what exactly is your question. explain it with some code or pictured

Answer (score 0):

**There are 3 cases that i can think about :** 
1)You have got some kind or warning for example :
Lets say that you are using google maps and want to add "current location button" - if you wont check if the user accepted location permission or not you will be able to run your app but you will have a warning in red line.
2)If some view is marked in red but everything compile with no errors , this is some error and cleaning and rebuilding your project should fix this
3)If some file name is marked as red , there may be some error/warning inside that file itself(for example - XML error inside some layout that allow yo to compile your app)

Answer (score 0):

@user462990 If you can't see any obvious issues. I'd suggest the static analyzer **Lint** tool. It inspects your code and would give you a detailed report of all issues wrong with your project.

Just go to **Analyze->Inspect Code**.

[image: Analyze->Inspect Code]

In the **Specify Inspection Scope** dialog that appears select **Whole project**.

[image: Specify Inspection Scope Dialog Window]

Lint inspects your code without building it and gives you a report of all the issues in the **Inspection Result** tool window at the bottom.

Clicking on any of those issues takes you to the editor at the exact line of code where the issue occurred.

See below captain **Lint** reporting for duty .

[image: Inspection Results]

Answer (score -1):

What's the problem...
[image]

It's the color of the "R" now it's red, it was . always black before.

I compressed the project and re-opened it again and the viewPager which was red is now black.

Comment: I think it's a non-issue probably the R.java file wasn't updated. Just do a build.